# Use direct proof to prove the following identity.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $3n^2+7\leq n^3, \forall n\ge 4.$

**My attempt**

I could prove it by principle of mathematical induction.
How do I prove using direct proof method?

$3n^2+7=3n^2+4+2+1\leq3n^2+n+2n+1\leq n^3+3n^2+n+2n+1=(n+1)^3 (\because 4\leq n, 2\leq 2n) $

I could prove $3n^2+7\leq (n+1)^3, \forall n\ge 4.$
Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

When $n\geq4$, we have $n^2\geq16>7$. So
$$3n^2+7<3n^2+n^2=4n^2\leq n\cdot n^2=n^3.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$n^3-3n^2-7=n^2(n-3)-7 \ge 4^2(4-3)-7=9>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Can't get more direct than this: $n\ge 4 \Rightarrow n=a+4,\ a\ge 0$.

Substituting, we see $3n^2+7=3a^2+24a+53$ and $n^3=a^3+12a^2+48a+64$.

Subtracting, $n^3-(3n^2+7)=a^3+9a^2+24a+11>0,\ \forall a\ge 0$, QED

Answer (score 0):

Calculus based alternative approach:

$f(n) = n^3 - 3n^2 - 7 \implies f'(n) = 3n^2 - 6n = 3n(n-2).$

Therefore,

- $f(4) > 0$.
- $\forall n \geq 4, f'(n) > 0 \implies$ $f(n)$ is strictly increasing on $(4,+\infty).$